# further afield -- is this an idiomatic expression?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Example with [a context](http://www.businessinsider.com/putins-next-move-on-ukraine-2015-2):

> **Further afield**, Russian forces have been deployed as "peacekeepers" in the Transdniestria region of Moldova since intervening to back separatists more than 20 years ago.

I think I've seen this expression used in analytical news stories a couple of times already, but I couldn't find anything about its usage online—seems to be pretty common, but no dictionary entries exist. I suppose it just means *moreover* or *furthermore*. But what do you think of this expression and where do you think this expression comes from?

Comment: [further/farther afield](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/afield): (=longer distances away, especially from home).

Comment: Have you tried searching for _define "further afield"_? That search returned many dictionary definitions and is the first thing I try when I'm trying to understand an unfamiliar phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a set phrase. It is idiomatic, but not really an idiom. Damkerng T. supplied a good link for its meaning.

However, the word "afield" rarely occurs except in "far/farther afield".

I forget what these constructions are called (stranded______?) wherein a word goes out of use singly, but survives in a set phrase:  "hither and yon" "nooks and crannies" "in fine fettle"  "short shrift" "days of yore"